# How to print a template to console in C++17?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, operator-overloading

I have this base template class:

```
template<typename Type>
struct InputBase {
    virtual void DisplaySingleResult(Type const& res) const {
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Therefore, this code below doesn't compile, because `vector` doesn't have a `<<` operator

```
struct Input : InputBase<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> {
    void DisplaySingleResult(std::vector<std::vector<int>> const& results) const override {
        for (std::vector<int> const& result : results) {
            std::cout << "[" << result[0] << "," << result[1] << "]";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};
```

When compiling, the method `InputBase::DisplaySingleResult` fails to compile because it uses `vector` type.

A workaround is to make the virtual `InputBase::DisplaySingleResult` method pure virtual.

However, I want to have a `DisplaySingleResult` method in my base class, with the same signature, to avoid rewriting all other derived classes. How to do that in C++17?

**Solution tentative:** in `InputBase::DisplaySingleResult`, check if the template Type has a `<<` operator before using it.

Comment: what do you want to do when `T` is a vector or any other type that does not have a `<<` ? You already mention a solution, but its not that clear what else you are looking for

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number This is solved case by case.

Comment: Why did someone vote to close this question?

Comment: because it isnt clear what you are looking for. "is solved case by case" isnt very enlightening. What do you want to do when `T` has no `operator<<` ? I made a guess and wrote an answer, but I can understand the reason for the vote

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I see, it wasn't clear indeed. When `T` has no `operator<<`, then the subclass handles this case (as does the `Input` class here). The base class provides a default behavior.

Comment: then i dont understand the quesiton. When put a check in the base for existance of `<<` and override the method for cases where there is none, all is fine, no?

Comment: This solution is hard to understand for a beginner programmer in C++

Answer (score 2):

I do not recommend to provide an overload for `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,const std::vector<T>&)` directly (not sure if it is even allowed). But indirectly.

Instead of calling `std::cout << res << std::endl;` you can call a function:

```
template<typename Type>
void print_result(const Type& res) { std::cout << res << std::endl; }

template<typename Type>
struct InputBase {
    virtual void DisplaySingleResult(Type const& res) const {
        print_result(res);
    }
};
```

Now you can provide overloads for any type that does not have a `operator<<`, eg

```
void print_result(const std::vector<int>& v) { for (const auto& e : v) print_result(e); }
```

To be more flexible with specializations you might want to consider to make `print_result` a class template rather than function template. For example there could be a specialization that calls `print_result` on the elements when `T` has `begin()` and `end()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could test at compile-time if the type is supported appropriately:

1. If there's a suitable output operator available already use it (this test assures that you don't use iterators if the type *can* be output directly, like e.g. `std::string`).
2. Otherwise if the type has `begin` and `end` functions use these.
3. Otherwise we are in an error condition!

This might look as follows:

```
template<typename Type>
struct InputBase
{
    static void displaySingleResult(Type const& res)
    {
        if constexpr (decltype(has_operator_out(res))::value)
        {
            std::cout << res;
        }
        else if constexpr
        (
            decltype(has_begin(res))::value && decltype(has_end(res))::value
        )
        {
            // your own desired formatting, e.g.:
            std::cout << '[';
            for(auto& r : res)
            {
                std::cout << r << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << ']';
        }
        else
        {
            // error handling:
            std::cout << "<invalid!>";
        }
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    static auto has_operator_out(T& t)
        -> decltype(std::cout << t, std::true_type());
    static std::false_type has_operator_out(...);
    template <typename T>
    static auto has_begin(T& t)
        -> decltype(t.begin(), std::true_type());
    static std::false_type has_begin(...);
    template <typename T>
    static auto has_end(T& t)
        -> decltype(t.end(), std::true_type());
    static std::false_type has_end(...);
};
```

Recursively calling the function instead comes allows to print nested containers as well (thanks [463035818_is_not_a_number](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/463035818-is-not-a-number) for the hint):

```
std::cout << '[';
for(auto& r : res)
{
    InputBase<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(r)>>>
        ::displaySingleResult(r);
    std::cout << ' ';
}
std::cout << ']';
```

Note that:

1. ... the function can be `static` as `this` is not used anywhere.
2. ... defining an `operator<<` instead would be more C++ like.
3. ... you might provide further tests or adjust the existing ones to your needs, e.g. for using `std::begin` and `std::end` instead.
4. ... there are other patterns possible for these tests, you might want to play around a bit with ;)

Comment: i'd rather call it recursively in case there is `begin` and `end` to make it also work for nested vectors.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Indeed ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have `DisplaySingleResult()` to be virtual, a typical way is to delegate to a non-virtual function, which can be a template:

```
virtual void DisplaySingleResult(Type const& res)
{
    DisplaySingleResultImpl(res);
}
```

Then you can templetize `DisplaySingleResultImpl()`. Now, in many cases, you don't want to do that in the base class (or only want to provide a typical implementation) - in these cases, CRTP comes to mind:

```
template<typename Type, typename Derived>
struct InputBase {
    virtual void DisplaySingleResult(Type const& res) const {
        static cast<const Derived&>(*this).DisplaySingleResultImpl(res);
    }
};

template<typename Type, typename Derived>
struct InputBaseWithCoutPrint : InputBase<Type, Derived> {
    void DisplaySingleResultImpl(Type const& res) const {
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
    }
};
```

CRTP is a very powerful tool, don't overuse it.